# ¿Cómo pasar datos de un Jtable a otro?

Tags: java

Necesito pasar unos datos de un `Jtable` a otra justo al seleccionar una fila de la primera `Jtable`.
Tengo una clase llamada (SuperForm) en la cual tengo un `Jtable` tipo `Object`. Esa `Jtable` la utilizo en dos clases: Cliente y Producto. Pero Los datos que registro en esas dos clases quiero registrarlos en una `Jtable` de otra clase.

Answer (score 1):

En general, un objeto `JTable` tiene asociado un objeto `TableModel` que guarda los datos. Entonces, para pasar filas de un `JTable` a otro, lo que tienes que hacer es leer el contenido del `TableModel` de origen y agregarlo al `TableModel` de destino.

Si estás utilizando un `DefaultTableModel` para guardar tus datos, puedes escribir un método que haga algo como esto:

```
JTable tblOrigen, 
       tblDestino;
/* Asigna tblOrigen y tblDestino para que apunte a los objetos JTable 
   del que necesitas leer los datos */
// tblOrigen = miObjetoJTableDeOrigen;
// tblDestino = miObjetoJTableDeDestino;
/*
   Aquí viene la parte interesante:
   Lee cada fila seleccionada de la tabla de origen 
   y agrégalo a la tabla de destino
 */
 DefaultTableModel tmO = (DefaultTableModel) tblOrigen.getModel(),
                   tmD = (DefaultTableModel) tblDestino.getModel();
 /* Si utilizas otro TableModel, el tipo de estas variables debe ser el mismo 
    que el TableModel que utilizas.
  */
 // Si tienes filas seleccionadas en la tabla de origen:
 if(tblOrigen.getSelectedRowCount() > 0) {
     // 1) Obtén los índices de las filas seleccionadas.
     int[] indices = tblOrigen.getSelectedRows();
     // 2) Para cada fila, crea un Array para guardar los valores... 
     for(int i : indices) {
         Object[] fila = new Object[tmO.getColumnCount()];
         // ... y guarda los valores de la fila de origen.
         for(int j = 0; j < fila.length; j++) {
             fila[j] = tmO.getValueAt(i, j);
         }
         // 3) Agrega la fila al TableModel de la tabla de destino
         tmD.addRow(fila);
     }
 }
```

Referencias:

- [The Java Tutorials: How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- [API del objeto JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)
- [API del objeto DefaultTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)

Answer (score 1):

Usa `ListSelectionListener` para saber cuándo se ha seleccionado una fila de la(s) tabla(s) origen para obtener las columnas que deseas. Luego, solo obtienes el `Model` de la tabla destino y por medio de `addRow` le asignas una nueva fila con los datos de las tablas origen.

```
tableOrigin.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(ListSelectionEvent e -> {
    int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
    // en caso necesites copiar todas las columnas, iteras las mismas
    int columnCount = table.getColumnCount();
    Object[] data = new Object[CANTIDAD_COLUMNAS];

    // guardas las columnas que se desea por medio de getValueAt

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tblTarget.getTableModel();
    model.addRow(data);
});
```